# Scrollbars in chrome does not disappear when document.documentElement.style.overflow="hidden";

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, scroll, scrollbar, hide

I want to hide scrollbars in Chrome and do

```
document.documentElement.style.overflow="hidden";
```

But if vertical scrollbar have not top position and horizontal scrollbar have not left position they does not disappear. This is my example http://jsfiddle.net/z6cwP/6/ .

Comment: you could add this to yiur hide function: `window.scrollTo(0,0);`

Comment: it works but in my situation i can't do this. position should stay the same.

Comment: You probably want `document.body.style.overflow="hidden";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay here is your anwser:
simply save the old scroll state, set the scroll position to zero, hide the scroll bars and return to the old position ;)

```
function hideScrollbars(){
    var x,y;
    x = window.scrollX;
    y = window.scrollY;
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);  
    document.documentElement.style.overflow="hidden";
    window.scrollTo(x, y);  
}

window.onload = function(){
    window.scrollTo(30, 30);  
}
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/z6cwP/7/

pls. don't forget to accept when useful :)

Answer (score 1):

use this one it work in chrome and mozilla also

```
function hideScrollbars(){
    //window.scrollTo(30, 30);
    document.documentElement.style.overflow="hidden";
}
```